# MS Word building block not inserted in its own page

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-2016

I defined a building block (QuickPart) to "Insert in its own page". I insert it in code (C# Word Interop) like this:

```
range =
    _doc.get_AttachedTemplate()
        .BuildingBlockEntries[blockName]
        .Insert(Where: _selection.Range, RichText: true);
```

_doc is _word.Documents.Add(...), _selection is _doc.ActiveWindow.Selection (nothing is selected) and _word is the Application object.

Based on the definition of the building block, I expect a page break to be automatically inserted before the building block but that is not happening. How do I make BuildingBlock.Insert honor the building block definition?

Comment: It appears that the object model does not honor that setting. My recommendation would be to format the first paragraph with "Page break before" paragraph formatting, and include a PageBreak at the end of the entry. Select all that, including the page break and re-create the Building Block.

Comment: If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Done :-) Thank you for checking back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the object model does not honor that setting. Apparently, only inserting the Building Block from the UI will trigger it.

My recommendation would be to:

1. Format the first paragraph of the Buidling Block entry with "Page
   break before" paragraph formatting.
2. Then include a PageBreak (Ctrl+Enter) at the end of the entry.
3. Select it, including the page break and re-create the Building
   Block.

In this way, the entire entry will always appear on a separate page from the rest of the text in the document.